# Insert values from textboxes to fields in website

Tags: c#, web, insert, textbox

I have 2 textboxes in C# application.
and I want to insert their values to 2 other textboxes that placed in a webPage(using webBrowser option that there is in C#)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Try:

```
string strValue = txtBox1.Text;
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.GetElementById("txtBox2").SetAttribute("Text", strValue);
```

Comment: This is what I used:

String strValue = textBox1.Text;

            HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;

            doc.GetElementById("txtEmail").SetAttribute("txtEmail", 
strValue);

I have 1 textBox in C# called "textBox1" and on textBox in the website called "txtEmail", and it didn't work

By the way: the textuBox in the website doesn't have ID setting, it only have "name:"txtEmail""

Comment: In your SetAttribute your first parameter is the name of the property of textbox you are setting...in this case "Text"

Comment: Yeah I know that's why I canged it to this:
String strValue = textBox1.Text;
            HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            doc.GetElementById("txtEmail").SetAttribute("Text", strValue);

and it's still not working

Comment: Try adding ID as txtEmail for your text box.

Comment: I can't, I'm using a random site which is not mine, and I need this specific website :\

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I guess you will somehow need permission to add the ID.

Comment: or there is another way to fill in the textBox that in the website without the ID part

Comment: Check out the last part in this URL - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also doesn't work,
I can't see what is the problem :(!

and also there is no explanation in the link for how to insert the info that i have in the textbox from the C# Application to the textbox from the website